# Why is TouchableHighlight starting as pressed / underlayColor?

Tags: react-native

The TouchableHighlight button appears as the underlayColor (pressed) on start up. I have to press it to have it go to its background color.

```
export default function ProductButton(props) {
  return (
      <TouchableHighlight
        underlayColor="#555"
        onPress={() => { 
            alert('Test');
        }}>
        <Text>
            Hello
        </Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
  );
}
```

Comment: it is working correctly as you have asked.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, the underlayColor is the color while it is being pressed. Why does it show up as this color when it is initialized?

Comment: because you are using underlayColor prop in TouchableHighlight

Comment: It has the same behavior if I don't use it. The default underlayColor is black.

Comment: Remove the underlayColor prop and it will be gone

Comment: As I previously stated, if I remove it, the pressed color is black. And it starts as black.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this `underlayColor = 'none'` like this to get no color on touch.

```
 <TouchableHighlight
 underlayColor='none'
    onPress={() => {
        alert('Test');
    }}>
    <Text>
        Hello
    </Text>
  </TouchableHighlight>
```

or you can also use **TouchableOpacity** like this:

```
    <TouchableOpacity
    onPress={() => {
        alert('Test');
    }}>
    <Text>
        Hello
    </Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm not clear. The problem is not the pressed / underlayColor. The problem is that it is instantiated with that color first until I press it. Once I press and release, it then goes back to its background color.

Comment: it is not happening with me. For me when I click it changes the background color

Comment: try using touchableOpacity

Comment: Glad I could help you :)

Comment: read about touches here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/handling-touches

Comment: you can use touchableNativeFeedback and TouchableWithoutFeedback also

Comment: I'll try the other 2. I do like the OnPress color change so TouchableOpacity is not for me. Thank you!

Comment: You can achieve the same onpress color change in all of them even in TouchableOpacity

Comment: upvote or accept the answer so that future readers can be benefitted.

Comment: I appreciate the alternatives but there is still a problem with TouchableHighlight

Comment: what problem? can you be more specific

Comment: TouchableHighlight instantiating with the underlayColor as its initial background color.

Comment: for that you can also use touchableNativeFeedback first read in the docs link that I shared above

Comment: Refer here too for activeOpacity prop and all other props are listed here  https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.59/touchablehighlight#activeopacity

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem.
It turns out I had imported TouchableHighlight from 'react-native-gesture-handler' instead of 'react-native'.
please check the import.